# How download a backup sql database from server with permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example I have a backup SQL Server database on IP : 192.168.1.2 and I want to get backup this database from other server.
SQL Server has permission but I haven't accessed to IP address.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You connect to the SQL Server on 192.168.1.2 using a tool like SSMS or SQLCMD.EXE and issue a backup command, which will create a backup file on 192.168.1.2. What do you mean by "haven't' access"? Do you mean you don't have RDP access?\

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have access to ip address  to initiate backup(assuming you have permissions to backup) unless your ip address is in blocked list..

You can just initiate a backup request

Comment: Hi.Can you wite a example for this problem?

Comment: @MojtabaNava:if you have ssms installed,you can search for `how to take backup` else you can search for how to take backup from sqlcmd